# Servlet showing 404 error on running in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

i am new in servlet programming. My tomcat is working fine in both eclipse and main system. When i am trying to run servlet, it showing 404 error. I made my servlet using dynamic web project. My code is :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class amar extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  response) throws  ServletException, IOException {

}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.getWriter().println("Hello friend!");
    response.getStatus();
}

}
```

Please help me to solve this problem. My web.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org  /xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
<display-name>first servlet</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: have you added servlet mapping in web.xml?

Comment: @kirti I didn't change anything in web.xml

Comment: plz show your web.xml... you must have a web.xml with servlet mapping in it

Answer (score 1):

Add mapping of servlet in web.xml.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>amar </servlet-name>  // name of servlet
    <servlet-class>packagename.amar </servlet-class> //packagename.class name
    </servlet>  

    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>amar </servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/amar </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Run it from browser as
    localhost:8080/projectname/amar

Comment: I can run it out of eclipse. But I wanna run in eclipse. I changed my web.XML but nothing happened in my favor. I created my servlet by dltk so it automatically generates web.XML.

Comment: I did not get you.. what do you mean by running in eclipse..For running on server via eclipse right click on project and select run on server and it should run.